# How to get g++ running on GNU Emacs on Windows 8.1?

Tags: c++, emacs, g++, cygwin, windows-8.1

I'm trying to set up g++/gcc/gdb so I can compile C/C++ code on my Windows 8.1 machine (Acer Aspire E 15 in case that helps) via Emacs. I've tried it with cygwin's terminal already but I'm more used to using g++ on emacs on Linux so I'd like to get the same on Windows.

I've downloaded cygwin and it works okay on its own but I can't seem to link cygwin and Emacs together (or get g++ to run in Emacs by itself) as when I try to compile in Emacs it throws up:

```
    g++ -g problem_7.cpp -o myprog
    'g++' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Has anyone got any ideas on what else I could do? Any feedback or alternatives would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you set up the environment variables for it?

Comment: Have a look at (http://www1.cmc.edu/pages/faculty/alee/g++/g++.html)

Comment: Here is a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637953/g-not-working-on-windows-command-prompt-cygwin-installed

Comment: @Ayush Thanks for getting back to me. I've set up the PATH variable, and taken a look at the cmc page but neither of them work for some reason. I'll take a look at mingw.

Comment: Which emacs are you using? If you use the Cygwin Emacs (I recommend emacs-w32 because it has better font rendering) it should just work. I do this all the time.

Comment: @PhilipDaniels I'm using MinGW now, I haven't had the chance to try it on a full program but it works on a test.